# Magento 2.3 Merged css and js. When are files from pub/static/_cache supposed to be created?

Tags: magento2.3, merge-css

I have a Magento 2.3.0 with js and css merging enabled.
My first issue is with the fact that the [docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/design/merge-css.html) say that this option only works in **developer** mode. This does not make any sense as the optimization should be for **production** environments.

My next question is when are the files under `pub/static/_cache` supposed to be created. From what I figure it is when they are **first requested**, which is not very logical as these file might get rather big and require **many resources** to be created.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are wrong abt merge working only in dev mode.

Files under pub/static/_cache are created at request time. So make sure there are enough permissions on the directory.

See this thread of files for more info:

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout::renderResult()
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::render()
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::assign()
\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer::renderHeadContent()
\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer::renderAssets()
\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer::renderAssetGroup()
\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Checksum::merge()
```

Or this github issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13225